# Changing colorbar title angle in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Consider the following code taken from [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/)

```py
import plotly.express as px
data=[[1, 25, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, 5, 20]]
fig = px.imshow(data,
                labels=dict(x="Day of Week", y="Time of Day", color="Productivity"),
                x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']
               )
fig.update_xaxes(side="top")
fig.show()
```

which produces the following plot
[image]

Is it possible to rotate the 'Productivity' title so that it shows up like this?
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that feature does not appear to be available at this time. See this plotly community [response](https://community.plotly.com/t/rotating-color-bar-title/73617).

Answer (score 2):

I found a way of doing it like this `fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar_title_side='right')` which is documented [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/#layout-coloraxis-colorbar-title-side).

Complete code:

```py
import plotly.express as px
data=[[1, 25, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, 5, 20]]
fig = px.imshow(data,
                labels=dict(x="Day of Week", y="Time of Day", color="Productivity"),
                x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']
               )
fig.update_xaxes(side="top")
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar_title_side='right')
fig.show()
```

and plot:
[image]